# Kafka Template to send records

Tags: spring-kafka

We have been using spring kafka 2.1 in our projects .There is a use case to ingest a message to all partitions in a topic so all consumers can identify an event.Is there  a way to  use kafkaTemplate to send a single record to all partitions of a kafka topic?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Partitioner` has an architecture like this:

```
/**
 * Compute the partition for the given record.
 *
 * @param topic The topic name
 * @param key The key to partition on (or null if no key)
 * @param keyBytes The serialized key to partition on( or null if no key)
 * @param value The value to partition on or null
 * @param valueBytes The serialized value to partition on or null
 * @param cluster The current cluster metadata
 */
public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster);
```

So, as you see there is no out-of-the-box way to determine several partitions at once.

What I only can suggest is something like send the same message to all the partitions manually in the loop.

What you are asking is just out of the Apache Kafka architecture.